# Помогите пожалуйста, настроить рендеринг страницы по шаблону loDash

Tags: javascript, шаблоны, lodash, jsrender

Помогите, пожалуйста, найти где ошибки: не полностью рендерится страница + не срабатывает вылет модального окна по нажатию на кнопку "Проверить результат":

```
var retObj = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("object"));
var html = $('#test').html();
var content = _.template(html)(retObj);
$("body").append(content);


https://plnkr.co/edit/3hzJzYxMOJv4YoGjgC7m?p=preview
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот здесь не хватало закрывающей угловой скобки для `<label .. >`:

```
<label for="<%= questions[i].id[j] %>"><%= questions[i].answers[j] %></label>
```

Поэтому не было видно текста.

А модальное окно не открывалось, потому, что не хватало открывающей угловой скобки у тега `div`:

```
var modal = $("<div class='modal'></div>");
```

Поправленный код на [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/fiXFCXrUev69004NmcYn?p=preview)